# How to remove branch with invalid character in name?

Tags: git, bitbucket, invalid-characters

I mistakely created a branch ”sandbox” (with these ”), and when I try to delete it, i'm getting this message:

```
$ git push origin :”sandbox”
remote: Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:   File     "/opt/python/domains/bitbucket.org/current/bitbucket/scripts/git/hooks/pre-receive", line 12, in <module>
remote:     sys.exit(prehooks.githooks())
remote:   File "/data/vol1/www/venvs/deployed/bitbucket/apps/repo2/git.py", line 1197, in wrapper
remote:     sha = repo._repo.lookup_reference(refname).sha
remote: pygit2.GitError: Failed to lookup reference 
remote:     - Failed to normalize name. Reference name contains invalid characters
To ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/git-repo.git
 ! [remote rejected] ”sandbox” (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://git@bitbucket.org/user/git-repo.git'
```

I tried to use urxvt as utf8 terminal.

I have githosting on bitbucket.org

Thanks
Zopper

Comment: Are you sure you already pushed it?

Comment: In a similar vein to @thejh I would ask are you sure it created a branch with the quotes?  I just tried the following `git branch "something"` and a branch named `something` was created -- i.e. **without** the quotes.

Comment: @SriSankaran, the OP is specifically talking about U+201D (right double quotation mark), not U+0022 (quotation mark).  It seems like bitbucket's code isn't handling the UTF-8 properly.

Comment: @SriSankaran - as jamessan typed - this is not quotation mark, but another character. Git branch show me: origin/”sandbox”.

Comment: @thejh: yes... this is the problem - I pushed it on server, so I can't easy delete it locally.

Comment: @Zopper, I'd suggest filing a bug against bitbucket, since it seems to be a problem on their side.

Comment: @jamessan I wrote email to bitbucket. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write the repository name safely in quotes (U+0022).

```
git push origin --delete "”sandbox”"
```